# Scrapy have one spider use a property built in another

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

So the issue is that I have one spider that crawls through a website, scraping a bunch of product information... Then I would like to have another which takes the list of product links built out in the first, and uses it to for checking purposes.

I realize I could just do this all in one spider, but the spider is already very large (is a generic spider for 25+ different domains), and would like to keep this as separated as possible. Currently I am creating instances of this master spider like follows:

```
def run_spiders(*urls, ajax=False):
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    for url in urls:
        process.crawl(MasterSpider, start_page = url, ajax_rendered = ajax)
    process.start()
```

Ideally how this would work is something like as seen in the following:

- [Scrapy run multiple spiders from a main spider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425666/scrapy-run-multiple-spiders-from-a-main-spider)
- [Is it possible to run another spider from Scrapy spider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176005/is-it-possible-to-run-another-spider-from-scrapy-spider)

I tried spawning another crawler process within the closed_handler of the MasterSpider, but the reactor is already running so clearly that isn't going to work. Any ideas?

Note that whenever i try to switch to a crawler runner, even if i go by what is exactly in the documentation/questions on here it doesn't exactly work. I'm thinking using the from_crawler might be my way to go, but i'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 0):

To chain multiple crawlers in a script you need to dive into Twisted deferred. [Official docs have this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) as a potential solution.

According to that code snippet we can create something like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy import signals

DATA = []

def store_item(*args, **kwargs):
    DATA.append(kwargs['item'])


class ProducerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'url': response.url}


class ConsumerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider2'

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in DATA:
            yield scrapy.Request(item['url'])

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'url': response.url}


configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    crawler1 = runner.create_crawler(ProducerSpider)
    crawler2 = runner.create_crawler(ConsumerSpider)
    crawler1.signals.connect(store_item, signals.item_scraped)
    crawler2.signals.connect(store_item, signals.item_scraped)
    yield runner.crawl(crawler1)
    yield runner.crawl(crawler2)
    reactor.stop()


crawl()
reactor.run()  # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
print('TOTAL RESULTS:')
print(DATA)
```

It's a bit long and hacky, but it's not as complicated as it looks:

1. Create two spider classes and an accessible/global variable to communicate through called `DATA`
2. Create `CrawlerRunner` instance to manage crawling.
3. Create a crawler for each spider and chain them to our runner.
4. Add signal to those our two crawlers to store their items to our shared variable `DATA`

So the first crawler crawls and puts every item through `store_item` function which just appends it to `DATA`. Then the second crawler starts and it's `start_requests` method reads directly from `DATA` to generate it's starting point.